# Replace column value by element of list from same column

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have the following dataframe. I applied the `str_split()` function to YEARS.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

YEARS <- c("2020/2021", "2021/2022", "2022/2023")  
VALUE <- c(10,5,3)  
x <- data.frame(YEARS, VALUE) %>%
     mutate(YEARS=str_split(YEARS, "/"))
```

I want to keep only the first element of the list for every YEARS, using dplyr if possible.
I tried this

```
x %>% mutate(YEARS=YEARS[[1]][1])
```

but it didn't work and just changed every value to 2020 :

| YEARS | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 10 |
| 2020 | 5 |
| 2020 | 3 |

I also tried with purrr but same result.
Does anyone kows why it's not working properly and how to fix it ?

Comment: Not sure about the desired output, but try `x %>% tidyr::unnest_wider(YEARS, names_sep="_") %>% select(-YEARS_2)`

Comment: or `x %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(YEARS = YEARS[1])`